# Angular $HTTP Post method only getting one array value in PHP

Tags: php, angularjs, phpmailer

I a using Angular $http to post an array to a php script. But the PHP script is only getting a single value from the array that I send with $http post from angular.

Angular form controller:

```
form.strategyData = {
    mailData : {
        strategies : ['test1','test2']
    },
    sent : false
}


form.processStrategy = function() {

    $http({
        method  : 'POST',
        url     : '/sform',
        data    : $httpParamSerializer(form.strategyData.mailData),
        headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    })

    .success(function(data) {
        console.log('success')
    });

};
```

PHP Script:

```
$strategies = $_POST['strategies'];
$message .= "Strategies: " . $strategies;
```

When I use console.log I do see the the 2 test values ['test1','test2'] inside the mailData

Inside PHP I only get the last value which is test2

Comment: try this $httpParamSerializerJQLike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call $httpParamSerializer(form.strategyData.mailData) your data send to server will be "strategies=test1&strategies=test2". That's reason inside PHP you get result is "test2".

Answer (score 0):

try `var_dump($strategies);` in your php script.

if you have all the values in your dump as array, update this line

```
$message .= "Strategies: " . $strategies;
```

to

```
$message .= "Strategies: " . implode(" ", $strategies);
```